# Checking Variable before allowing click

Tags: c#

How do I have it check my variable before allowing a click.

Example :

```
_StartControl.Click += new EventHandler(StartControl_Click);
```

I only want them to be able to do that if my variable "isValid" is equal to 1.

I'm not very good at forms.. Have always learned just console apps.

Comment: You could add the if-check in the StartControl_Click method itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the value of your isValid field inside StartControl_Click method. If the value is 1, you can allow the method to proceed, if it's not 1, you can simply return from the method before anything gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
if(isValid==1)
  _StartControl.Click += new EventHandler(StartControl_Click);
```

Comment: If isValid is meant to be changed during runtime, that solution would not work.